# Show that the $l^p$ norms with $1\leq p,q\leq \infty$ are equivalent

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

I want to show that for any $1\leq p,q\leq \infty$, that there exists $a,b$ such that $a\left\|x\right\|_p \leq \left\|x\right\|_q \leq b\left\|x\right|_p$ for all $x$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$.
Is there a way to do this without Hölder's Inequalities?

Comment: I am able to do this in the case of the 2-norm and infinity norm with a =1 and b =sqrt(n), is the proof similar to this specific case?

Comment: Yes: it is quite elementary when $p=\infty$, and the general case follows.

Comment: What is $X$ here?

Comment: Its the set of R^n

Comment: Well, we do have to be careful. When e.g., $q =\infty$ and $p=1$ the constants $a$ and $b$ may depend on $n$. I would imagine that the OP wants $a$ and $b$ to be of the form $a=a(p,q)$ and $b=b(p,q)$ where both $a,a^{-1},b,b^{-1}$ are functions of $p$ and $q$ only--no matter how large $n$ may be

Comment: *Although from the wording of the question, perhaps not.

Comment: Mike: trouble is, this has to depend on $n$. Else all the $\ell^p$ norms would be equivalent on the space of sequences with finitely many nonzero terms.

Comment: yes, a and b depending on n will suffice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\|x\|_{\infty} \leq 1$ implies $\|x\|_{p} \leq n^{1/p}$ for any $p \in [1,\infty)$. Use this and a scaling argument to show that $\|x\|_{p} \leq n^{1/p} \|x\|_{\infty}$. [You have to consider $y=\frac x {\|x\|_{\infty}}$ when $x \neq 0$]. On the other hand, $  \|x\|_{\infty} \leq \|x\|_{p} $ because  $|x_i| \leq \|x\|_{p} $ for each $i$. Hence all of the $p$-norms with $p<\infty$ are equivalent to $\infty$ norm. This implies that any two of the  $p$-norms are equivalent. [ $\|x\|' \leq c\|x\|''$ and $\|x\|'' \leq d\|x\|'''$ implies $\|x\|' \leq cd\|x\|'''$ etc].